# How to wait for iSpeech to finish speaking before passing the next string

Tags: ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue, ispeech

Im using iSpeech API.  I've posted in their forums but there is not much activity over there.  I can pass it a string and have the app speak it.  But now I want to pass in an array of strings, say 5.  I want the engine to speak those strings one after the other but it only speaks the first one.  I decided to use NSOperationQueue so in my viewDidLoad I did:

```
//Create Queue
    queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
    [queue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
```

And then later I do this:

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

  ```
  //Set loop for 5 strings
  [self fetchStringsToSpeak:indexPath];
  ```

  }

  -(void)fetchStringsToSpeak:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath{

  ```
  int stringsToSpeak = 5;

  for (int counter = 0; counter < stringsToSpeak; counter++) {

      //Get the string
      NSDictionary *currentString = [self.stringsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+counter];

      //3. Fill im text and image for cell
      NSString *string = [currentString objectForKey:@"text"];

      //Clean the string from URLs
      NSError *error;
      NSDataDetector *linkDetector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:&error];
      NSArray *matches = [linkDetector matchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
      NSLog(@"matches %@", matches);

      if ([matches count] > 0) {
          for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
              if ([match resultType] == NSTextCheckingTypeLink) {
                  NSString *linkToRemove = [[match URL] absoluteString];
                  self.cleanString = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:linkToRemove withString:@""];
                  NSLog(@"Clean string: %@", self.cleanString);

              }
          }
      } else {
          NSLog(@"NO LINK");
          self.cleanString = string;
      } //END IF/ELSE

  NSInvocationOperation *operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc]initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(speakAString:) object:self.cleanString];
  [queue addOperation:operation];

  //Message back to the main thread
  [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(taDah) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];

  } //END FOR LOOP
  ```

  }

  - (void)speakAString:(NSString*)stringToSpeak {
    ISSpeechSynthesis *synthesis = [[ISSpeechSynthesis alloc] initWithText:stringToSpeak];
    NSError *err;
    if(![synthesis speak:&err]) {
        NSLog(@"ERROR: %@", err);
    }
    self.cleanString = nil;
    }

It is passed the values by these methods:

It speaks the first one but then I get this:

> Domain=com.ispeech.ispeechsdk.ErrorDomain Code=303 "The SDK is already
>   performing synthesis or recognition. Wait for that to finish before
>   starting another request." UserInfo=0xb54f2b0
>   {NSLocalizedDescription=The SDK is already performing synthesis or
>   recognition. Wait for that to finish before starting another request.}

Why is the operation queue not waiting?